# Fragmentation in modern file systems

Tags: file, linux-kernel, operating-system, filesystems

I was tinkering with Pintos OS file system and wonder:

How do modern file systems handle fragmentation issue, including internal, external and data?

Comment: Fragmentation of what?

Comment: The file is located at different sectors not a continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it's file fragmentation you are interested in.

The answer is it depends entirely on the file system and the operating system. In the case of traditional eunuchs file systems, the disk is inherently fragmented. There is no concept whatsoever of contiguous files. Files are stored in changed data blocks. This is why paging is done to partitions and most database systems on eunuchs use partitions.

"Hard" file systems that allow contiguous files manage them in different ways. A file consists of one or more "extents." If the initial extent gets filled, the file system manager creates a new extent and chains to it.In some systems there are many options for file creation. One can specify the initial size of the file  and reserve space for subsequent allocations (ie, the size of the first extent and the size of additional extents).

When a hard file system gets fragmented, there are different approaches for dealing with it. In some systems, the normal way of "defragging" is to do an image back up to secondary storage then restore. This can be part of the normal system maintenance process.

Other system use "defragging" utilities that either run as part of the regular system schedule or are manually run.

The problem of disk fragmentation is often exaggerated. If you have a disk with a reasonable amount of space, you don't really tend to get much file fragmentation. Disk fragmentation—yes; but this is not really much of a problem if you have sufficient free disk space. File fragmentation occurs when (1) you don't have enough free contiguous disk space or (2) [most likely with reasonable disk space] you have a file that continually gets added data.

Answer (score 1):

Most file systems indeed have ways to deal with fragmentation. I'll however describe the situations for the usual file systems that are not too complex.

For **Ext2**, for each file there are 12 direct block pointers that point to the blocks where the file is contained. If they are not enough, there is one singly indirect block that points to `block_size / 4` blocks. If they are still not enough, there is a doubly indirect block that points to `block_size / 4` singly indirect blocks. If not yet enough, there is a triply indirect block that points to `block_size / 4` doubly indirect blocks. This way, the file system allows fragmentation at block boundaries.

For **ISO 9660**, which is the usual file system for CDs and DVDs, the file system doesn't support fragmentation as is. However, it's possible to use multiple consecutive directory records in order to split a big (more than 2G/4G, the maximum describable file size) file into describable files. This might cause fragmentation.

For **FAT**, the file allocation table describes the location and status of all data clusters on the disk in order to allow fragmentation. So when reading the next cluster, the driver looks up in the file allocation table to find the number of the next cluster.